# How to set relative path in gulp

Tags: batch-file, gulp, relative-path

I am a beginner in gulp. I am facing issue while setting up the relative path.
My objective is to create a gulp command to execute a batch file(placed at a specifiv location.)

If I give absolute path of the batch file, gulp commad runs smoothly but as soon as I try to change absolute path with relative path command fails.

Please suggest how to use relative path.
below is what I am trying to do: (This works well)

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var batchFileLocation ='C:/Project/Main/Portal/Project.Phase.Delivery/Templates/test.bat';
gulp.task('buildLa', function () {
exec(batchFileLocation, function () {
 });
})
```

But when I try this, it fails

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var batchFileLocation ='./../../Portal/Project.Phase.Delivery/Templates/test.bat';
gulp.task('buildLa', function () {
exec(batchFileLocation, function () {
 });
})
```

Comment: from which current directory are you running your script?

Comment: My gulpFile and batch file are placed in same directory but in different folders

Comment: Can you post the actual windows directory from which you start your gulp script?

Comment: I start my gulp script from here :

    c:/Project/Main/Support/Client/GD/

Comment: starting from your Client/GD path, you go up twice which puts you in `c:/Project/Main/Support` Add one extra `..` or you're unable to reach `Portal`. Simple as that

Answer (score 1):

```
gulp.task("run", function () {

    process.chdir('../<folder>');

});
```